# How do I adapt an Activity in android from fragment transaction?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this code:

```
public void replaceFragment(int i) {
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    TextView headerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HeaderName);
    switch (i) {
        // Login Fragment
        case 0:
            headerName.setText("Member Login");
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new 
            LoginActivity());
            break;
        // Register Fragment
        case 1:
            headerName.setText("Sign Up");
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new RegisterFragment());
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem is on the case 0, I put the other cases as examples. My login is not a Fragment, but an Activity. So how do I manage to keep it here? With an Intent?

Comment: Start Activity using startActivity method instead of adding it as Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new 
                LoginActivity());
```

Use

```
Intent inntent = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(inntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build a new intent in case 0 and start your activity instead of trying to replace a fragment with activity which is impossible unless you turn your activity to fragment

If you need both you can turn your activity to fragment and then build an empty activity to contain it when necessary